# How you treat multiple implementations for one method?

Tags: c++

I have a method which have three implementations. I would like to keep them all in the source code.

What is the usual practice to do this?

I am thinking like giving three implementation three different names , like methodX1, methodX2 and methodX3, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: More details, please. What do you mean by three implementations? Different implementations for different platforms? Or do the methods share a lot of common code? Or are they completely different implementations, and some other part of the code dynamically chooses which one to execute?

Answer (score 2):

The common wisdom is against repeating implementations, however there may be various reasons to do so, for example keeping different variants of legacy code.

If you are bound on keeping all the different implementations instead of refactoring the common parts, you should still try and have one method that you call elsewhere in the code, for example, via an (inlined) dispatch method that will select one of the implementations according to an enum parameter that describes the gist of the differences.

This is to abstract away implementation details and make later refactoring and mocking for testing a tad easier.

Dispatching will look roughly like this:

```
enum MethodImpl { NO_SORT, Q_SORT, MERGE_SORT };

void method(const arg& arg, MethodImpl  impl) {
    switch(impl) {
    case MethodImpl::NO_SORT: methodX1(arg); break;
    ...
    };
}
```

The second option is to wrap the methods in subclasses with a common base class interface, and let the language polymorphically select the relevant implementation according to the instantiation of the concrete chosen implementation in the other parts of the code where you chose to use the methods.

```
class IMethod {
public:
    virtual ~IMethod();
    virtual method() = 0; 
};

class MethodX1_Impl : public IMethod {
public:
    virtual method() { methodX1(); } 
};
class MethodX2_Impl : public IMethod {
public:
    virtual method() { methodX2(); } 
}
...
```

I'll avoid describing the third option, the selection of a concrete implementation with a template instantiation - since it doesn't differ much from the dispatch option and might introduce requirements to implement certain parts in header files only.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of separating in different methods, you can section out code within the same method using preprocessor directives. This is normally done in cross-platform projects to execute certain code for various OS's.